# Add items to git index efficiently

Tags: git, bash

I find it very tedious to write full paths when adding changed files to index. For example, i've changed 3 files, but want to commit only 2 of them:

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   apps/frontend/config/modules/file1
#   modified:   apps/frontend/config/modules/file2
#   modified:   apps/frontend/config/modules/file3
```

So I have to type as much as:

```
git add app/frontend/modules/file1 app/frontend/modules/file3
```

I am looking for a way to add items by their index in the git status list? Something like

```
git add %1 %3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `interactive` add:

```
git add -i
```

It'll ask you for each file, if you want to add it to the commit.

You can even go ahead and pick based on patches, which is always useful:

```
git add -p
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd apps/frontend/config/modules
git add file1 file3
cd - #go back
```

Comment: Note that "cd -" is shell specific.  (ie, it won't work in all shells)

Comment: @WilliamPursell `cd -` is in POSIX. Oh, csh? Well, use `pushd` and `popd` then.

Comment: @Giles I did not realize it was POSIX, and thought it was a bashism.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use shell expansion:

`git add app/frontend/modules/file{1,3}`

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a similar script I wrote to add only 1 file, e.g. `git nadd N` to add the N'th modified file. It shouldn't be hard to modify it to allow several files.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# != 1 ]] ; then
    echo "usage: git nadd <index>"
    exit 0
fi

num=$1

# get unstaged modified files
modified_files=$(git status --porcelain | grep " M " | cut -c 4-)

if [[ $modified_files == "" ]] ; then
    echo "error: there are no modified files"
    exit 1
fi

# count how many we have
num_modified_files=$(echo "$modified_files" | wc -l)

if [[ $num -gt $num_modified_files ]] ; then
    echo "error: index larger than number of modified files"
    exit 2
fi

# pick n'th modified file
file=$(echo "$modified_files" | sed -n "$num p")

# fix $file to full path in case we're not in root
root=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
file=$root$file

git add -- "$file"
```

Comment: Use an array: `modified_files=($(...))`, `num_modified_files=${#modified_files[@]}`, `file=${modified_files[num]}`. Also, you can do `if (( num > num_modified_files ))`.